# DCP Rule Error in the Optimization Problem

Tags: optimization, cvxpy, convex-optimization, mosek

I have an optimization problem where the following constraint causes "DCP Rule Error".

[image]

Assuming that rho_n and x_n are among the decision variables and B is constant. Is this constraint convex?

I tried to write the Python code of the optimization problem using the cvxpy library and the mosek solver, but the above clause causes a DCP Rule Error.

Comment: Do you know anything about the sign of B?

Comment: Surely b is positive.